# SonarQube false positive S1450 for VS 2017 RC C#

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I think I have found a false positive while using a private readonly variable.
In the following example I get a warning: **Remove the "_a" field and declare it as a local variable in the relevant method.** [S1450](http://www.sonarlint.org/visualstudio/rules/index.html#version=1.22.0.1615&ruleId=S1450)

```
public class MyClass : MyBaseClass
{
   private readonly string _a;

   public MyClass(string a)
   {
     _a = a;
   }

   public override string ToMyString(){
      var test = new MyNewClass(_a);
      return test.MyValue();
   }
}
```

(ToMyString is acually alot more complex then my above example)

Am I doing something wrong here or is this false positive?

I am using C# .Net Core on VS 2017 RC3 with SonarAnalyzer.CSharp 1.22.0-RC1

Answer (score 0):

I will make more test tomorrow but for now I can't reproduce the issue. Here is the test code I am using (based on your partial example). Could you tell me if this code is raising the issue? If not, could you provide a full repro case?

```
public class MyClass : MyBaseClass
{
    private readonly string _a;

    public MyClass(string a)
    {
        _a = a;
    }

    public override string ToMyString()
    {
        var test = new MyNewClass(_a);
        return test.MyValue();
    }
}

class MyNewClass
{
    private readonly string _a;

    public MyNewClass(string _a)
    {
        this._a = _a;
    }

    public string MyValue() { return _a; }
}
```

Comment: FWIW I have the bug with the following code, that should be compilable anywhere:
```
    class UpdateListener:
    {
        private readonly string data;
        private readonly string libraryActivity;

        public UpdateListener(string libraryActivity, string data)
        {
            this.data = data;
            this.libraryActivity = libraryActivity;
        }

        public void OnUpdate(string update)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(update);
            Console.WriteLine(data);
            Console.WriteLine(libraryActivity);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thx I will have a look to see if I can reproduce.